# Does Vishnu care only about his devotees?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, bhakti

I had read somewhere that Vishnu is not concerned about anyone or suffering of anyone as everyone gets the fruits of their Karma only.
But He is concerned only for his Bhakts, is involved in their lives and really cares about them and always protects them.
How true is this ?

Has Vishnu or Krishna anywhere said any such thing explicitly ?

Answer (score 1):

If Vishnu didn't care about others this world would be damned to ruination. God has a dharma for all living beings in Hinduism, not just his Bhaktas. However, his Bhakatas (Vaishnavas) seek him and wish to attain the lord's abode almost like children wishing to meet their eternal father. So, your first part of the question is incorrect. Lemme provide Bhagavad Gita verses for scriptural testimony.
Bhagavad Gita 3.24: https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/3/verse/24
Bhagavad Gita 7.25: https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/7/verse/23
Bhagavad Gita 9.16-17: https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/9/verse/16-17

As for Karma the goal is to break free of it and Samsara. In the Bhagavad Gita Krishna teaches how through him one can achieve such it's up to you to choose this path or not however, and your action will have a result.

The Srimad Bhagavatam does talk about how a sinner was allowed into Vaikunta for simply saying the word Vishnu before death as that cleared all of them, but the Puranas are usually exaggerated and dramatized to fit a particular message. Also are highly sect-biased and not very authentic compared to Vedas, Upanishads, and Ithihasas. Hope this helps!!!

Comment: You should quote the verses and explain how they support your argument.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that God looks after devotees.

**God helps His devotees**

> Whoever, being devoted to Me solely, engage themselves always in
> contemplation and worship of Me – to such ever-steadfast devotees I
> ensure the procurement of their assets (worldly interests).

**Gita 9.22**

It is also true that the Lord does not normally interfere in the working of the universe although it is run by His power.

> At the end of a cosmic cycle, O son of Kunti! All beings resolve into
> Nature (Prakrti), which is My own, and at the beginning of a new one
> (after the period of dissolution or Pralaya is over), I bring them out
> again.

**Gita 9.7**

> Resorting to Prakrti, Nature, which is My own Power, I send forth
> again and again this multitude of beings that are without any freedom,
> owing to Nature’s sway over them.

**Gita 9.8**

> These activities do not in any way bind Me, because I remain detached
> like one unconcerned in their midst.

**Gita 9.9**

> Under My direction and control, Nature brings out this mighty universe
> of living and non-living beings. Thus does the wheel of this world
> revolve.

**Gita 9.10**

However, it would not be correct to say that Vishnu cares only about His devotees. The point here is that those who are not His devotees don't show any interest in Vishnu and Vishnu allows such a person the freedom to live his life in the way he wants.

An analogy would be a fire burning in a very cold place. A person has the right to walk towards the fire and get relief from the cold. Another person has the equal right to turn away from the fire and suffer from the cold. The fire is Lord Vishnu, the person who turns towards the fire is a devotee and the person who turns away from the fire is not a devotee. You can't blame Lord Vishnu for the suffering of the person who is not a devotee. It is the choice of the person. Such a person has to live his life according to his Karma.

Gita also says that God is same to all.

> I am the same towards all beings. None is hateful, and none, dear to
> Me. But those who worship Me with devotion dwell in Me, and I too
> dwell in them.

**Gita 9.29**

Answer (score 1):

In PadmaPurana, Sri Krsna narrates the story of a Brahmana who was a Saura (Sun-Worshipper) who used to be very religious in worshipping Surya. Sri Narayana was so pleased by just that, that he gave him a place in Vaikuntha. Here, we have a clear mention of him caring about a bhakta other than just his own.

**---- Padma Purana,Uttara Khanda,Chapter 88 ----**

> **Śrīkṛṣṇa said:**
>
> 34-45. O dear one, listen attentively. I shall tell you all about the
> auspicious vow you observed in your former existence. At the end of
> the Kṛta age in Māyāpurī there was an excellent brāhmaṇa of Atri’s
> family, Devaśarman by name, who had mastered the Vedas and the
> Vedāṅgas. He was hospitable. He attended (sacred) fire. **He was
> greatly devoted to the vow (in honour) of the Sun. Actually being like
> another Sun, he everyday propitiated the Sun.** The old man had a
> daughter, Guṇavatī by name. Being sonless, he gave his daughter to his
> disciple named Candra(śarman). He (i.e. Devaśarman) looked upon him as
> his (own) son, and he who had controlled his passions, looked upon him
> as his father. **The two, desiring to collect kuśas and fuel, once
> went to a forest. The two then roamed in the forest at the foot of the
> Himālaya mountain. Then they saw a fierce demon coming (to them). With
> their entire body overcome by fear, and unable to run (away), they
> were killed by the demon with Death-like form. My attendants, moving
> with me, took them to Vaikuṇṭha-abode due to the efficacy of the
> region and their religiousness. I was indeed very much pleased with
> them by virtue of just that act of them, viz. they, as long as they
> were alive, worshipped the Sun etc. As the rainwater goes to the
> ocean, the followers of Śiva, the Sun, Gaṇeśa, Viṣṇu, so also the
> worshippers of Śakti come |to me only. I am one, born in five ways,
> and play with names—as one Devadatta calls his sons etc. with
> (various) names.** Then the two lived in my house; moved in an
> aeroplane; had the brilliance of the Sun; resembled me in form; were
> near me; enjoyed divine beautiful women and pleasures like (being
> smeared with) sandal.

So In his own words as well as actions, he cares about everyone, be it Shaiva, Vaisnava, Shakta, saura or Ganpatya

Answer (score 0):

According to the structure of Hinduism , the bhakti is a form of mental communication with the Devas.

Through this dhyaana, concentration in meditating on the God, the devotee is feeling the protection of the God, as it is described in many scriptures such as Hanuman Chalisa https://greenmesg.org/stotras/hanuman/hanuman_chalisa.php

As far as it can be understood, also Bhagwan Vishnu and His aavatar Krishna can be reached through bhakti.

This does not mean that, generically speaking, there is a carelesness in this relationship between humans and God as it is unmentioned in all the scriptures.

And that is because the relationship between humans and God is personal.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such things.

Shiva Purana 2.1.10.:

> Viṣṇu said:—
>
> 27. “O Sankara, the ocean of mercy, the lord of the universe, be pleased to hear. I shall do all these things strictly adhering to your behests.
> 28. I shall always meditate upon you. I would not act otherwise. Your omnipotency has already been experienced by me.
> 29. O lord, let not the meditation of your form be ever far removed from my mind even for a moment.
> 30. O lord, if anyone of my devotees were to censure you, you will please assign perpetual residence in hell to him.
> 31. **O lord, whoever be your devotee shall also be my favourite. He who knows and realises this shall not find salvation inaccessible to him.**
> 32. My greatness has been further heightened by you certainly. If ever I am found deficient in qualities I may be excused.

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..